# Check if element is visible by percentage area after scrolling?

Tags: javascript, scroll, visibility, percentage, getboundingclientrect

How to detect visibility element **by percentage area** 50% or more?
[image: visibility element by percentage JS]

Javascript:

```
var i = setInterval(function() {

var el = document.getElementById('test');
var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

if(
  rect.top >= 0 &&
  rect.left >= 0 &&
  rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
  rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) == true) {
  var div = document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = 'Visible';
  //clearInterval(i);
}
  else {
    var div = document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = 'No visible';
  }

},1000);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rd2d2/otpep4dm/)

Comment: So what's the question? Your jsfiddle appears to work correctly in both Firefox and Chrome. It initially says "No visible" but if I scroll the box into view it changes to "Visible."

Comment: I need at least 50% of the measured element are in sight.

Answer (score 0):

I added 50% of the element height (rect.height/2) to the condition. Now it detects even if the elements is only 50% visible.

```
var i = setInterval(function() {

var el = document.getElementById('test');
var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(window.innerHeight)  
  console.log(rect) 
if(
  rect.top >= 0 &&
  rect.left >= 0 &&
  rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight+(rect.height/2) || document.documentElement.clientHeight+(rect.height/2) ) &&
  rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) == true) {
  var div = document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = 'Visible';
  //clearInterval(i);
}
  else {
    var div = document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = 'No visible';
  }
},1000);
```

Comment: Thank you. But it's not right. Look at the pictures, 50% area element are in sight. Scroll right, top/bottom - together.